# distribute nodes evenly

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I am trying to built a graph by manually placing the nodes using relative placement. But I face some issues with the way the nodes are placed. I tried to include it in a MWE:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    test node/.style={rectangle, draw, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex}
]
    \small

    \node (a) [test node] {First node};
    \node (b) [test node, above right=of a] {Upper branch 1};
    \node (c) [test node, below right=of a] {Lower branch 1};

    \begin{scope}[red]
        \foreach \pos/\n in {above right/x, right/y, below right/z}
            {
                \node (\n) [circle, draw, \pos=of a] {};
                \foreach \a in {north, center, south}
                {
                    \draw[shift=(\n.\a)] plot [mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
                }
            }
        \foreach \n in {x, y, z}
            \draw (0,2 -| \n.center) -- ++(0,-4);
        \node [circle, draw, below=of a] at (3,0) {};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the placement of the circles and of the text nodes relative to the first node does not match. Secondly, the three circles do not align horizontally.
And as a third "bonus", the last circle placed with a combination of the `below` key and an explicit position in x-direction is mismatched in a third way.

What is right way to place such nodes (with different shapes and different ways to place them) without manually adding coordinates? I need to combine different shapes and I need to set some x-coordinates explicitly to correctly distribute the nodes in different branches...

Edit: To clarify: I would like to vertically align the circles and the rectangles, and I would like to horizontally align their west anchors.

Comment: You can change the node anchor `anchor=west` for example.

Comment: As far as I know, this is done automatically when using the keyword `right`. Otherwise the nodes would not end up next to each other but overlap.

Comment: My problem is that no anchors of the different nodes align. Neither the center of the red circles align with the center of the text node, nor the north or south anchor or the west or east anchor

Comment: Try with `anchor=base west`

Comment: Doesn't change a thing. Why should it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to vertically align all placed nodes, and I would like to align the west anchors of the circles and the rectangles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\node (b) [test node, above right=of a] {Upper branch 1};
```

sets the `anchor` of node `b` to `south west` and *not* to `west`. Then `b.south west` is positioned 1cm to the right and 1cm above of `a.north east`. And if the node is a circle there is difference in `x`-direction between anchor `south west` and `west`.

If the anchor of `b` should be `west` instead of `south west` you have to use `anchor=west` *after* the option `above right=of a`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    test node/.style={rectangle, draw, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex},
    node distance=1cm and 1cm
]
    \small

    \node (a) [test node] {First node};
    \node (b) [test node, above right=of a,anchor=west] {Upper branch 1};
    \node (c) [test node, below right=of a,anchor=west] {Lower branch 1};

    \begin{scope}[red]
        \foreach \pos/\n in {above right/x, right/y, below right/z}
            {
                \node (\n) [circle, draw, \pos=of a,anchor=west] {};
                \foreach \a in {north, center, south}
                {
                    \draw[shift=(\n.\a)] plot [mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
                }
            }
        \foreach \n in {x, y, z}
            \draw (0,2 -| \n.center) -- ++(0,-4);
        \node [circle, draw, below=of a] at (3,0) {};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[green](a.east)--+(1,0);
    \draw[blue](a.north east)--++(1,0)--+(0,1);
    \draw[orange](a.south east)--++(1,0)--+(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

And maybe you want to position the `west` anchors relatively to the `east` anchor of `a`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    test node/.style={rectangle, draw, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex},
    node distance=1cm and 1cm
]
    \small

    \node (a) [test node] {First node};
    \node (b) [test node, above right=of a.east,anchor=west] {Upper branch 1};
    \node (c) [test node, below right=of a.east,anchor=west] {Lower branch 1};

    \begin{scope}[red]
        \foreach \pos/\n in {above right/x, right/y, below right/z}
            {
                \node (\n) [circle, draw, \pos=of a.east,anchor=west] {};
                \foreach \a in {north, center, south}
                {
                    \draw[shift=(\n.\a)] plot [mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)};
                }
            }
        \foreach \n in {x, y, z}
            \draw (0,2 -| \n.center) -- ++(0,-4);
        \node [circle, draw, below=of a] at (3,0) {};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[green](a.east)--+(1,0);
    \draw[blue](a.east)++(1,0)--+(0,1);
    \draw[orange](a.east)++(1,0)--+(0,-1);
    \draw[purple](a.center)--++(0,-1)--+(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This cleared things up significantly, thank you very much! I didnt realize this although i read the corresponding parts of the manual twice...